# How do I access JSON data that is stored as a time series dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull out the `"4. close"` field value for each date within `"Time Series (Daily)"` for the JSON data in the format below.

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-11-22 13:46:00",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2019-11-22": {
            "1. open": "150.0700",
            "2. high": "150.3000",
            "3. low": "148.8200",
            "4. close": "149.4350",
            "5. volume": "8155350"
        },
        "2019-11-21": {
            "1. open": "149.4000",
            "2. high": "149.8000",
            "3. low": "148.5100",
            "4. close": "149.4800",
            "5. volume": "16125077"
        },
        "2019-11-20": {
            "1. open": "150.3100",
            "2. high": "150.8400",
            "3. low": "148.4600",
            "4. close": "149.6200",
            "5. volume": "25696800"
```

I have tried the code below:

```
for item in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
    print (item)
    print (item[0]['4. close'])
```

The `print(item)` line works as expected and returns the date value e.g. `"2019-11-21"` within `"Time Series (Daily)"`, but I am having trouble accessing the value pairs for each of the date keys.

Specifically, I would like to return the value from the key: value `"4. close": "149.4800"` for each date in `"Time Series (Daily)"`.

I have tried a few things such as `print(item[0]['4. close'])` but this and other attempts have just produce a traceback error.

Comment: `item` is the *key*, `data['Time Series (Daily)'][item]` is (one way to get the) value.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe that's a huge help. I ended up adjusting to data['Time Series (Daily)'][item]['4. close'] to get the close value but couldn't have gotten there without your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
for item in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
```

Gives you only the keys in that dictionary. That's why `print(item)` prints only the key which is the date. This should work:

```
for key, value in data['Time Series (Daily)'].items():
    print(key) # the date
    print(value['4. close']) # the expected output
```

Another option:

```
for item in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
    print(item) # same as before
    print(data['Time Series (Daily)'][item]['4. close'])
```

A one-liner loop to get all of them at once:

```
print({key: value['4. close'] for key, value in data['Time Series (Daily)'].items()})
```

A working example of all 3:

```
>>> for key, value in data['Time Series (Daily)'].items():
...     print(key) # the date
...     print(value['4. close']) # the expected output
...
2019-11-22
149.4350
2019-11-21
149.4800
2019-11-20
149.6200
>>> for item in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
...     print(item) # same as before
...     print(data['Time Series (Daily)'][item]['4. close'])
...
2019-11-22
149.4350
2019-11-21
149.4800
2019-11-20
149.6200
>>> print({key: value['4. close'] for key, value in data['Time Series (Daily)'].items()})
{'2019-11-22': '149.4350', '2019-11-21': '149.4800', '2019-11-20': '149.6200'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers and great explanation @ofer-sadan!

Comment: @OferSadan you may hint out, how he should do that, by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jonrsharpe!

item is the key, data`['Time Series (Daily)'][item]` is (one way to get the) value. – jonrsharpe

Thank you @jonrsharpe that's a huge help. I ended up adjusting to `data['Time Series (Daily)'][item]['4. close']` to get the close value but couldn't have gotten there without your help. Thank you very much!